# fibonacci recursion ruby explanation

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, fibonacci

I know how to solve this problem without recursion, but with it, I am having some difficulty understanding..I need a deep explanation of how this works line by line

Here is how the problem is done:

```
def fibo(num)
  if num < 2
    num
  else
    #this is where I get lost on the line below..
    fibo(num-1) + fibo(num-2)
  end
end

p fibo(6)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Fibonacci sequence, each number in the sequence after the first 2 is the sum of the previous 2 numbers:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, ...
```

When you write a recursive function, you explicitly handle the base cases (which are `fibo(0)` and `fibo(1)` in your case), and then anything else is computed by calling the function you are writing, building up later results by operating on earlier ones.

By definition, after the first 2 numbers in the sequence, a Fibonacci number is the sum of the previous 2 numbers.  In other words, fibo(n) = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2).  This is what this line of code is doing:

```
fibo(num-1) + fibo(num-2)
```

It is returning the value of fibo(num) by calling itself (that is "recursion") for the previous 2 numbers and adding them together.

Because they are base cases, we know fibo(0) will be 0, and fibo(1) will be 1.  Let's look at how this works for fibo(4):

```
fibo(4) = fibo(3) + fibo(2)
fibo(4) = (fibo(2) + fibo(1)) + (fibo(1) + fibo(0))
        = (fibo(2) +    1   ) + (   1    +    0   )
        = (fibo(2) + 2)
        = ((fibo(1) + fibo(0)) + 2
        =     1     +    0     + 2
        = 3
```

So, the program eventually computes the correct result by breaking each computation into simpler problems until it reaches the base case which has defined answer.  Note that this is not very efficient, since the `fibo` is called 9 times to compute `fibo(4)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know stack frame, you can better understand recursion. Let's take a simpler x = Fib(3) to show the stack frame change.

(1) When calling Fib(3), Fib function's stack is like this with 3 as parameter: |   |
                                                                                | 3 |

(2) when Fib(3) went to the line Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2), the stack is like this:   |   |
                                                                                | 2 |
                                                                                | 3 |

(3) then this Fib(2) is evaluated into Fib(1)+Fib(0), the stack is like this:   | 1 |
                                                                                | 2 |
                                                                                | 3 |

(4) fib(1) returns the value 1, now it's fib(0)'s turn to be evaluated:         | 0 |
                                                                                | 2 |
                                                                                | 3 |

(5) Fib(0) returns 0, now Fib(2)'s value is 1 and is returned to Fib(3),        | 1 |
    now Fib(3) need another part, Fib(1), the stack is like this:               | 3 |

(6) Fib(1) returns 1, now Fib(3) is evaluated as 2, and get returned, stack is empty.

Edit: why StackOverflow does not keep the format?
Altenatively, please refer to this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

or this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0bb7UYy0pY

Answer (score 0):

First, it is good to understand that fundamentally there is no difference between iteration and recursion and the problem that can be solved using the iterative method can be solved recursively and the other way around.

For this particular example, take a look at this drawing. It shows what's going on step by step: http://natashatherobot.com/wp-content/uploads/fibonacci.png

This post will be useful to read: http://natashatherobot.com/recursion-factorials-fibonacci-ruby/